# Query with jpa multi-tables

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have a jpql query to join multi-tables but when I debug it returns null results 
and when I execute it in oracle it works fine , the tables don't have any relation foreign key just the columns are the same , so can you help me how can I resolve this problem

```
Query qDetailCnx = em.createQuery(
            "select distinct t1.pdpStartTime, 
                             t1.name1 ,
                             t1.ipAddr, 
                             t1.imsi,t1.tac_code, 
                             t4.constructeur, 
                             t4.modele, 
                             t4.typeTerm, 
                             t2.type,
                             t5.type,
                             t3.type, 
                             t3.signification 
    from ConnexionEntity t1, 
         RatEntity t2, 
         EndRATEntity t5, 
         EndCauseEntity  t3, 
         HandsetEntity t4 
    where t1.name2=:name2 
    and starttime BETWEEN to_date(:startDate,'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:mi:ss') 
    and to_date(:endDate,'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:mi:ss') 
    and t1.rat= t2.code 
    and t1.endrat= t5.code 
    and t1.endcause = t3.code 
    and t1.tac_code=t4.code 
    order by pdpstarttime");
qDetailCnx.setParameter("name2",choix.getMsisdn() );
qDetailCnx.setParameter("startDate", convert.convertDateTime(choix.getStartdate()) );
qDetailCnx.setParameter("endDate", convert.convertDateTime(choix.getEndDate()));
```

my query executed by hibernate :
Hibernate: select distinct connexione0_.PDPSTARTTIME as col_0_0_, connexione0_.NAME1 as col_1_0_, connexione0_.IPADDR as col_2_0_, connexione0_.IMSI as col_3_0_, connexione0_.TAC_CODE as col_4_0_, handsetent4_. CONSTRUCTEUR as col_5_0_, handsetent4_. MODELE  as col_6_0_, handsetent4_. TYPETERM  as col_7_0_, ratentity1_.TYPE as col_8_0_, endratenti2_.TYPE as col_9_0_, endcauseen3_.TYPE  as col_10_0_, endcauseen3_. SIGNIFICATION  as col_11_0_ from KPI.CONNEXION_DWHS connexione0_, KPI.  RAT  ratentity1_, KPI.  ENDRAT  endratenti2_, KPI.END_CAUSE endcauseen3_, KPI.  HANDSET  handsetent4_ where connexione0_.NAME2=? and (starttime between to_date(?, 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:mi:ss') and to_date(?, 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:mi:ss')) and connexione0_.RAT=ratentity1_.CODE and connexione0_.ENDRAT=endratenti2_.CODE and connexione0_.ENDCAUSE=endcauseen3_.CODE  and connexione0_.TAC_CODE=handsetent4_.CODE order by pdpstarttime

Comment: please add query generated by hibernate to your post.

Comment: Thanks Rasoul Taheri , it's done , any ideas please

Comment: i think you should use your field with their parent. for example your have 2 field without parent i your query. `starttime` and `pdpstarttime`.  `pdpstarttime` is for table `ConnexionEntity` then write 't1.pdpStartTime' instead of pdpStartTime in order clause. also do it for start time. im not ensure this was your problem, but you can test it.

Comment: no It does'nt work !!